# How do I caption videos using Large Language Models

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, large-language-model

I want to generate captions for videos for a Machine Learning task. I have tried captioning videos using miniGPT4 or CoCap, which is slow (a few minutes on the CPU). Is there a good approach to getting decent video captions (preferably a few seconds)?